# Is it good practice having separate database for different pages in a website?

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-services, phpmyadmin

I have a website `xyz.com` that is going to be launched in an online server. I have three pages `x`, `y` and `z` (suppose `x` is for image gallery, `y` is for video gallery, and `z` is for another gallery). I need to have a comment section for each of the pages, and user input is going to be stored in database. There need not be any relation between the comments in different pages, or in another words, comment from one page doesn't have to relate with the comments in another pages. I want to deal them separately.

Now my question is:

Should I use one database and create just three different tables for each pages or should I create three completely different database each of them having one table? Which one is good practice?

Comment: Why would you want to create a separate *database* for every table?  MySQL is perfectly capable of having multiple tables.  Quite good at it, in fact.

Comment: **1** db and  **1** table just add a reference to the page in the comments table

Comment: Agreed. One database. One table.

Comment: @rtfm, Strawberry: I disagree. One database one table is not best practise. If one page is extended or refactored, you might have to separate your data afterwards. The overhead for 3 against 1 table is not that big.

Comment: @nCessity its only for comments

Comment: One could split the difference and have a `Comments` super-table with the identifiers and common properties for all comments.  Properties added to specific *kinds* of comments could be put in type-specific sub-tables whose PK is a FK to the super-table.  Any of the designs being recommended in this comments is valid, depending on the direction the owner intends to take with the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create the different databases and why would you?

1. Create single database
2. Create 2 tables "`galleries`" and "`comments`"

   ```
   galleries (id|title|name|type|date etc....)
   ```

Gallery `type` can be "image" or "video" or etc...

3. when you load data for image(s) page do

   ```
   select * from galleries where type='image'
   ```

and when for video

```
select * from galleries where type='video'
```

so on...

**For comments:**

create table

```
comments (id|comment_text|gallery_type...)
```

where `gallery_type` is the foreign key

**If your gallery types are lots you can always create a sperate table for gallery_types and give reference accordingly.**

Answer (score 0):

Use one database with as many tables as you need, there's no reason to create several databases for your project